# Failed to connect to policy server while using Pure Java Agent API

Tags: java, api, agent, siteminder

I have been using the JNI agent for the past few weeks and after adding the reference to dll and jar, it was working fine for me. Recently I tried to change it to Pure Java Agent by changing the JAR. I am getting the following error:

> FATAL: Failed trying to connect to the Policy Server. Ensure that the Agent Name and Shared Secret in smjsdkexample.properties matches that of a pre-existing agent in the Policy Store.

Comment: And do the Agent Name and Shared Secret in the properties file match a pre-existing agent in the Policy Store?

Comment: yes. it does. It still works fine if i just change back to the JNI jar